# Need help downgrading Call and Text on Other Devices APK (its a system app in /system/app) on Galaxy Watch 4 - repost since rejected on other forumn

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

So first off, I'm using a Galaxy Watch 4 Classic LTE from Samsung, and on all devices samsung has this feature called Call and Text on Other Devices, where you can text from your tablet or watch using your phone number and take calls as long as all devices are connected to the same WiFi network.

There is the call and text on other devices apk on the LTE watch, but the app is basically a dud since it disables Remote Connection --> calls on other devices. Samsung deliberately left out this feature on the LTE watches so you would be forced to buy an LTE plan with one of the big carriers with the US.

I wanted to see if I can re-enable this feature on my LTE watch, and I got the idea of trying to downgrade from 5.1.00.10 (the dud call and text thingy) to 5.1.00.9 (the one that actually works, russian guy on russian forum said that his bluetooth galaxy watch had this version number https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=1065200&st=40)

I tried a lot of commands in adb through my PC.

First, I tried uninstalling the one already stored in my watch, ./adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 -k com.samsung.android.mdecservice

Then, I downloaded Call and Text on Other Devices (specifically for wearOS) version 5.1.00.9 https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsu...evices-wear-os-5-1-00-9-android-apk-download/ and pushed it to /data/local/tmp/

Then I tried running this command: pm install -i PrePackageInstaller /data/local/tmp/

Every time it gets me this error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Downgrade detected: Update version code 510000009 is older than current 510000010] . I did some digging and found out that version 5.1.00.10 was flashed onto the OS on system image. I was wondering if I can find a way to get around this issue and get this to install. I don't want root because itll trip off the knox chip and I need it for samsung pay

Specifically, I also ran ./adb shell pm install -r -d /data/local/tmp/ and it gave me this error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: System app: com.samsung.android.mdecservice cannot be downgraded to older than its preloaded version on the system image. Update version code 510000009 is older than current 510000010]. That's my indication that it wont allow me to downgrade apps older than system image which sucks.

My issue is most similar to this person where they tried to downgrade samsung notes but can't because its a system app https://xdaforums.com/t/how-do-i-permanently-downgrade-system-apps.4548193/

Is there a workaround I can possibly do? I don't really want to purchase a new galaxy watch just because samsung disabled one feature but based on the amount of time I spent on the ADB debug bridge I am starting to get convinced I should.

My steps:

1. ./adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 -k com.samsung.android.mdecservice
2. Downloaded mdecservice version 5.1.00.9 from apkmirror.com
3. pm install -i PrePackageInstaller /data/local/tmp/. This gives me the error: *Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Downgrade detected: Update version code 510000009 is older than current 510000010]*
4. alternate commmand: ./adb shell pm install -r -d /data/local/tmp/. Failure message: *Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: System app: com.samsung.android.mdecservice cannot be downgraded to older than its preloaded version on the system image. Update version code 510000009 is older than current 510000010].

- 